# Create a matrix with elements taken by another matrix

Tags: c, matrix, indexing, copy, element

I have to implement a function which, given a matrix of 0s and 1s, returns a new matrix that contains the coordinates of the 1s. For example: if matrix is 3x3 and the output is:

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

New matrix will be 5x2 and the output will be:

```
0 0
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
```

Some advice? My method would be this:

```
int matrix[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if (matrix[i][i] == 1){
            //Code i need
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution really depends on the requirement:

1. Is it allowed to allocate result matrix with the maximum size possible (in this case 9 x 2).
2. If point 1 is not allowed, is it strictly required to use fixed size array (no dynamic allocation). If this is the case then may need to pass the matrix twice to allocate the right size of array.

Other solution is of course by using dynamic allocation (using malloc etc).
The simplified version of option 1 & 2 is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    int matrix[3][3];
    matrix[0][0] = 1;
    matrix[0][1] = 0;
    matrix[0][2] = 1;
    matrix[1][0] = 0;
    matrix[1][1] = 1;
    matrix[1][2] = 1;
    matrix[2][0] = 0;
    matrix[2][1] = 0;
    matrix[2][2] = 1;

    //Solution 1 - If allowed to allocate matrix with size more than the result,
    //i.e. if input is 3x3 matrix, then the maximum size of result matrix is 9 x 2
    int resultMatrix1[9][2];
    int usedCount1=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                resultMatrix1[usedCount1][0] = i;
                resultMatrix1[usedCount1][1] = j;
                usedCount1++;
            } //end if
        } //end for
    } //end for
    //Print the result
    printf("\nSolution 1\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < usedCount1; i++){
        printf("%d %d\n", resultMatrix1[i][0], resultMatrix1[i][1]);
    } //end for


    //Solution 2 - strictly allocate matrix with size equal to the result.
    //Without using dynamic allocation, meaning we need to have two passes.

    //1st pass is to count the element which satisfy the criteria
    int usedCount2=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                usedCount2++;
            } //end if
        } //end for
    } //end for

    int resultMatrix2[usedCount2][2]; //allocate the right size
    int idx=0;
    //2nd pass is to fill in the result matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                resultMatrix2[idx][0] = i;
                resultMatrix2[idx][1] = j;
                idx++;
            } //end if
        } //end for
    } //end for

    //Print the result
    printf("\nSolution 2\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < usedCount2; i++){
        printf("%d %d\n", resultMatrix2[i][0], resultMatrix2[i][1]);
    } //end for

    return 0;
}
```

Results are the same for both solution:

```
Solution 1
0 0
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2

Solution 2
0 0
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If `matrix[i][j] == 1` what do you know about the coordinates `[i,j]` ? That they are the coordinates of a `1` :)

Secondly, will the input matrix always be 3x3? If not, you'll want to store the dimensions of the matrix in variables, and use theses variables for your `for` loops.